Clarification needed: Changing PIT IDs in Elasticsearch
The Elasticsearch documentation for version 7.17 states:

The open point in time request and each subsequent search request can return different id; thus always use the most recently received id for the next search request.

(Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/point-in-time-api.html)
This statement is unclear. When the documentation mentions that subsequent requests can return different PIT ids, it's not evident whether:

A new Point in Time (PIT) context has been created, or
The id has changed, but we're still operating within the same PIT context.

Clarification on this point would be helpful for understanding the behavior and proper usage of the Point in Time API.
